# What exactly is the "stage number" in git revisions

Tags: git

In the git [revisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) it says:

> [:], e.g. :0:README, :README
> A colon, optionally followed by a stage number (0 to 3) and a colon, followed by a path, names a blob object in the index at the given path. A missing stage number (and the colon that follows it) names a stage 0 entry. During a merge, stage 1 is the common ancestor, stage 2 is the target branch’s version (typically the current branch), and stage 3 is the version from the branch which is being merged.

To me this does not clarify what stage number :0, :1, :2 and :3 mean. The documentation mentions the case, when a merge is being done. But it does not mention what they mean when no merge is in progress.

Trying it out, it seems to me ":0" is the currently staged index. Is that correct?

- Does the meaning of ":0" etc. change when a merge is in progress?
- What do the number mean when no merge is currently in progress?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These numbers *all* represent "slots" in the index / staging area. There are two situations to distinguish:

#### Merge conflict

When paused during a merge *conflict*, when Git rewrites your conflicted files for you, if you ask about a conflicted file, `:0:` is empty; that is why, after you edit the working tree version you have to `add` it, to get the fixed version into the index so that it goes into the merge commit.

Meanwhile:

- `:1:` is the state of this file in the LCA (the merge-base)
- `:2:` is the `ours` version
- `:3:` is the `theirs` version

So, assuming you know what a merge is, you can conclude from this that Git attempted to apply both the diff `:1:`-`:2:` and the diff `:1:`-`:3:` to `:1:` to form the new file to go into the merge commit, and couldn't do it without human assistance (hence the "conflict").

#### Otherwise

Otherwise, `:0:` is the index version of a file and the *others* are all empty (and trying to fetch one will result in an error message).

Comment: @Nathan But it is possible that I should take out the word "conflict" from my explanation and that this is true for _every_ file during a merge except that `:0:` is _not_ empty for non-conflicted files. I'll double-check the next time I have a merge to do!

Comment: @Nathan, no change needed! I tried pausing in the middle of a merge (by using `--no-commit`) and `:1:` etc. were empty. So my "merge conflict vs. other" contrast is correct.